# Access and store large amount of data from mysql server

Tags: php, android, mysql, ios, sqlite

We are developing an `iOS`/`Android` application which downloads large amounts of data from a server.

We're using `JSON` to transfer data between the server and client devices.

Recently the size of our data increased a lot (about 30000 records).

When fetching this data, the server request gets timed out and no data gets fetched.

Can anyone suggest the best method to achieve a fast transfer of data?

Is there any method to prepare data initially and download data later?

Is there any advantage of using multiple databases in the device(`SQLite` dbS) and perform parallel insertion into db's?

Currently we are downloading/uploading only changed data (using `UUID` and time-stamp).

Is there any best approach to achieve this efficiently?

---- Edit -----

i think its not only the problem of mysql records, at peak times multiple devices are connecting to the server to access data, so connections also goes to waiting. we are using performance server. i am mainly looking for a solution to handle this sync in device. any good method to simplify the sync or make it faster using multi threading, multiple sqlite db etc,...? or data compression, using views or ...?

Comment: `Recently size of data increased to large size like 30000 records, then server request get timed out and no data get fetched on the request`: If you are having to fetch all 30000 records together for display, you are ***almost certainly*** doing it wrong. Othrwise 30,000 records are nothing for a MySQL database. Even 3 million are nothing

Comment: you never fetch such an amount of data at once. Use `paging` like the messages are loaded in facebook or twitter. Research on that.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky : i know its not large amount of data but it takes too much time to get data based on multiple conditions and create json etc. in future there is chance to increase the size of data further, we are looking for a long term solution to handle this situation.

Comment: But why do you have to fetch 30,000 records together? If that's not the case and the fetch is still slow then have a DBA go through the database schema and look for proper normalization and indexes to start with

Comment: i think its not only the problem of mysql records, at peak times multiple devices are connecting to the server to access data, so connections also goes to waiting. we are using performance server. i am mainly looking for a solution to handle this sync in device. any good method to simplify the sync or make it faster using multi threading, multiple sqlite db etc,...? or data compression, using views or ...?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to achieve this would probably be to download no data at all.

I guess you won't be showing these 30k lines at your client, so why download them in the first place?

It would probably be better to create an API on your server which would help the mobile devices to communicate with the database so the clients would only download the data they actually need / want.

Then, with a cache system on the mobile side you could make yourself sure that clients won't download the same thing every time and that content they have already seen would be available off-line.

Comment: Also, revise your database structure, normalize your data and set-up proper indices.

Answer (score 0):

> When fetching this data, the server request gets timed out and no data gets fetched.

Are you talking only about reads or writes, too?

If you are talking about writing access, as well: Are the 30,000 the result of a single insert/update? Are you using a transactional engine like InnoDB, e.g.? If so, Are your queries wrapped in a single transaction? Having auto commit mode enabled can lead to massive performance issues:

> Wrap several modifications into a single transaction to reduce the number of flush operations. InnoDB must flush the log to disk at each transaction commit if that transaction made modifications to the database. The rotation speed of a disk is typically at most 167 revolutions/second (for a 10,000RPM disk), which constrains the number of commits to the same 167th of a second if the disk does not “fool” the operating system.
>
> [**Source**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-tuning.html)
>
> Can anyone suggest the best method to achieve a fast transfer of data?

How complex is your query designed? Inner or outer joins, correlated or non-correlated subqueries, etc? Use `EXPLAIN` to inspect the efficiency? [Read about EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)

Also, take a look at your table design: Have you made use of [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)? Are you indexing properly?

> Is there any method to prepare data initially and download data later?

How do you mean that? Maybe temporary tables could do the trick.

But without knowing any details of your project, downloading 30,000 records on a mobile at one time sounds weird to me. Probably your application/DB-design needs to be reviewd.

Anyway, for any data that need not be updated/inserted directly to the database use a local SQLite on the mobile. This is much faster, as SQLite is a file-based DB and the data doesn't need to be transferred over the net.